# Finding the list of successors of an Instruction in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I want to get the list of successors for each instruction in  llvm. If I understood correctly, for all instruction except branch (br), the successor instruction is the next one. But for branch instructions is a bit more tricky.

For example, If I have the following C code:

```
int main() {
  int a = 7;
  int b = a * 2;

  int x;
  if (a < 3) {
    x = 10 + b;
  } else {
    x = 20 + a;
  }
  return b;
```

}

I get the following ByteCode:

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
%1 = mul nsw i32 7, 2
%2 = icmp slt i32 7, 3
br i1 %2, label %3, label %5

; <label>:3:                                      ; preds = %0
%4 = add nsw i32 10, %1
br label %7

; <label>:5:                                      ; preds = %0
%6 = add nsw i32 20, 7
br label %7

; <label>:7:                                      ; preds = %5, %3
ret i32 %1
}
```

So the instructions

> br i1 %2, label %3, label %5

have 2 successors:

> {%4 = add new i32 10, %1,  %6 = add nsw i32 20, 7}

How can I get access to the successors from the instruction?

Note: What I am actually trying to do is dead code elimination. I know that llvm has some methods such as IsInstructionTriviallyDead() in live-analysis library. For practising purposes, I'm not planning on using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the basic blocks that the instruction can branch to using the [`getSuccessor(unsigned)`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BranchInst.html#ad97f2e60cf22f15e0cf617af52309031) & [`getNumSuccessors()`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BranchInst.html#a96b8f11f6f21ca0321294669dab83b35) methods on [`BranchInst`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BranchInst.html). Given a `BasicBlock *BB`, you can then access the first instruction via [`BB->front()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#ad5ed50ae3c824584f1a97ded8d0b6750).

Comment: Thank you so much :) Yes that works. Just out of curiosity, is there a way that this can be done using iterators? So say putting the instructions of all BasicBlocks in a vector and iterating through them?